# Find longest consecutive zeros in 3D-array along axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I find the longest consecutive zeros in a 3D array along a specific axis?

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.random.randint(2, size=(10, 10, 10))
```

I want to find the longest sequence of `0` along `axis=0` so that I get a `10x10` array.

In one dimension it works with:

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.random.randint(2, size=100)

condition = (a==0)
L = np.diff(np.where(np.concatenate(([condition[0]],
                                     condition[:-1] != condition[1:],
                                     [True])))[0])[::2]
print(np.max(L))
```

Comment: What's the content of your desired `10 x 10` array? The count of zeros for the longest consecutive zeros along that axis?

Comment: @HansHirse Yes the length of the longest consecutive zeros series along the zeroth axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform your task, define the following function:

```
def longestZeroSeqLength(a):
    # Changes in "isZero" for consecutive elements
    chg = np.abs(np.diff(np.equal(a, 0).view(np.int8), prepend=[0], append=[0]))
    # Ranges of "isZero" elements
    rng = np.where(chg == 1)[0]
    if rng.size == 0: return 0    # All non-zero elements
    rng = rng.reshape(-1, 2)
    # Compute length of each range and return the biggest
    return np.subtract(rng[:,1], rng[:,0]).max()
```

Then apply it to your array:

```
result = np.apply_along_axis(longestZeroSeqLength, 0, a)
```

To test it, I created the following (smaller) array:

```
siz = (3, 4, 5)
np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.randint(2, size=siz)
```

After running my code I got:

```
array([[1, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 1, 0, 3],
       [3, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

To easier assess what contains each slice and what is each partial
result, you can run:

```
for j in range(a.shape[1]):
    for k in range(a.shape[2]):
        b = a[:, j, k]
        res = longestZeroSeqLength(b)
        print(f'{j}, {k}: {b}, {res}')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `np.cumsum()` to sum up the `1`s and `0`s along a given dimension.
The idea is that, when you have consecutive zeros the value in the cumsum stays the same. So in the end you want to find the most common value in this array, as its count is exactly the length of the longest sequence of zeros (+1).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

# 1D, bincount
a = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
#                    ^  ^  ^  ^
b = np.cumsum(a)
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6])
#                    ^  ^  ^  ^
c = np.bincount(b)
# array([0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1])
#                    ^

res = np.max(c) - 1
# 4
```

`bincount` unfortunately works only for 1D arrays, so for the multidimensional case, I switch to `scipy.stats.mode`, which returns just  the modal (most common) value and its count.

```
# 1D, stats.mode 
c2 = mode(b)
# ModeResult(mode=array([4]), count=array([5]))
res = c2[1] - 1

# 3D, stas.mode
from scipy.stats import mode
axis = 0
a = np.random.randint(2, size=(10, 10, 10))
res = mode(np.cumsum(a, axis=axis), axis=axis)[1] - 1
# Note the resulting shape is (1, 10, 10) 
# You might want to use np.squeeze() / np.max() 
# to get rid of the dimension with size 1
# res = res.max(axis=axis)
```

## EDIT

As @clearseplex pointed out, I didn't think of the case when the array starts with 0.

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])

b = np.cumsum(a)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4])
#        ^  ^  ^
```

There are 3 zeros, but if I subtract one I get the wrong result. So the correct solution is to subtract only if the most common value is not `0`.
So the correct way is:

```
m, res = mode(np.cumsum(a, axis=axis), axis=axis)
res[m != 0] -= 1
# res = res.argmax(axis)
```

Comment: I think your code does not account for zeros on the edges.

Comment: ```siz = (10, 10)
np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.randint(2, size=siz)``` gives ```[3 2 2 3 1 3 2 2 2 7]``` but should be ```[3 2 3 3 1 3 2 2 2 8]```

Comment: This is a very smart idea, thank you for submitting it.