How to correctly extract white pixels from binary images and display them correctly on the plotlib?
This is a binary image, I want to calculate the distance between two edges of the pixel, then display it on a drawing board. I handle it when it does not have branches, but when it has branches like figure, I don't know how to correct the display on board.
This is figure1 I can handle it like this:

figure1 outcome that drawing on board:

The issue is when it has intersection points and branches How can I correctly display it on board?
The image that has branches:

False displayed images:

My Python script is:
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
from matplotlib.colorbar import ColorbarBase

matplotlib.rc("font", family='Microsoft YaHei')

image_path = r'E:\data\ground_truth\1089_13.jpg'

image = Image.open(image_path)
image_array = np.array(image)

white_points = np.column_stack(np.where(image_array == 255))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,7))


ax.set_xlim(0, 600)
ax.set_ylim(0, 600)
ax.invert_yaxis() 

ax.plot(white_points[:, 1], white_points[:, 0], 'w')

left_points = []
right_points = []
for y in np.unique(white_points[:, 0]):
    row_points = white_points[white_points[:, 0] == y]
    if len(row_points) > 1:
        left_point = row_points[np.argmin(row_points[:, 1])]
        right_point = row_points[np.argmax(row_points[:, 1])]
        left_points.append(left_point)
        right_points.append(right_point)

left_points = np.array(left_points)
right_points = np.array(right_points)


ax.plot(left_points[:, 1], left_points[:, 0], c='#FF0000', lw=0.5)
ax.plot(right_points[:, 1], right_points[:, 0], c='#FF0000', lw=0.5)

max_distance = 0
max_distance_pair = (None, None)
min_distance = float('inf')
min_distance_pair = (None, None)

distances = []
for left_point, right_point in zip(left_points, right_points):
    distance = euclidean(left_point, right_point)
    distances.append(distance)
    if distance > max_distance:
        max_distance = distance
        max_distance_pair = (left_point, right_point)
    if distance < min_distance:
        min_distance = distance
        min_distance_pair = (left_point, right_point)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
bounds = np.linspace(0, max(distances), num=8)
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

for left_point, right_point, distance in zip(left_points, right_points, distances):
    color = cmap(norm(distance))
    ax.plot([left_point[1], right_point[1]], [left_point[0], right_point[0]], color=color, lw=0.5)

if len(left_points) > 0 and len(right_points) > 0:
    ax.plot([left_points[0][1], right_points[0][1]], [left_points[0][0], right_points[0][0]], 'SeaGreen', lw=0.5)
if len(left_points) > 0 and len(right_points) > 0:
    ax.plot([left_points[-1][1], right_points[-1][1]], [left_points[-1][0], right_points[-1][0]], 'SeaGreen', lw=0.5)

if max_distance_pair[0] is not None and max_distance_pair[1] is not None:
    print(f'Maximum distance: {max_distance}')
    print(f'Coordinates of the points with maximum distance: {max_distance_pair[0]}, {max_distance_pair[1]}')

if min_distance_pair[0] is not None and min_distance_pair[1] is not None:
    print(f'Minimum distance: {min_distance}')
    print(f'Coordinates of the points with minimum distance: {min_distance_pair[0]}, {min_distance_pair[1]}')

crack_width_max = max_distance / 10  
crack_width_min = min_distance / 10  

if max_distance_pair[0] is not None and max_distance_pair[1] is not None:
    ax.plot([max_distance_pair[0][1], max_distance_pair[1][1]],
            [max_distance_pair[0][0], max_distance_pair[1][0]],
            '#1E90FF', lw=1, label=f'crack_max_width: {crack_width_max}cm')
if min_distance_pair[0] is not None and min_distance_pair[1] is not None:
    ax.plot([min_distance_pair[0][1], min_distance_pair[1][1]],
            [min_distance_pair[0][0], min_distance_pair[1][0]],
            'b-', lw=1, label=f'crack_min_width: {crack_width_min}cm')

print(f'crack_max_width: {crack_width_max}cm')
print(f'crack_min_width: {crack_width_min}cm')


cb_ax = fig.add_axes([0.91, 0.1, 0.03, 0.78]) #[0.92, 0.1, 0.02, 0.8]
cb = ColorbarBase(cb_ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, boundaries=bounds, ticks=bounds, orientation='vertical')
#cb.set_label('the distance')

ax.legend().set_visible(True)

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(True)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(True)

plt.show()



Display branches correctly on board.
Calculate the distance between two edges if there are the two branches are also calculated separately.


for question 2 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63939224/3944322

You can try this code:
import numpy as np
import cv2
im=cv2.imread('test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im=cv2.threshold(im, 128, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
result=np.zeros_like(im, dtype='uint32')
diff=np.diff(im.astype(np.int8), axis=1)
y,x_min=np.nonzero(diff==1)
_,x_max=np.nonzero(diff==-1)
value=x_max-x_min
for i in range(x_min.size):
    result[y[i],x_min[i]:x_max[i]]=value[i]


But, for your task, distance transformation would be better suited.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html

That's awesome
